# Console build with post-build events in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake, post-build-event

I'm using CMake. That is the cmake "install" instruction:

```
install(TARGETS MainProject
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Install/bin"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Install/lib"
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Install/bin"
)
```

In Windows CMake creates project "INSTALL", that relates to project "BUILD_ALL", that relates to all real projects listed in `CMakeLists.txt` files.
Project "INSTALL" have post-build event, that performs "install" actions.

But when I run it with `devenv INSTALL.vcxproj /rebuild "Release|x64"`, post-build event are not performed.

Does there exists way to perform post-build events of Visual Studio from console?

(I need console, because build have to be run from scripts)

Comment: There might be a condition on the post-build event, I wouldn't know what else could prevent it from running. Open INSTALL.vcxproj in a text editor and see what the post-build event looks like. Also to build using the command line you don't really need devenv, just `msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj` should be ok.

Comment: I did. Post build event is looks like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake`, and it works if I run it from console. So, this workaround would help.
But I want it to be performed at part of build, where it should be.

Comment: Does `cmake --build . --target INSTALL --config Release` work?

Comment: What you show is just the post-build Command, not any possible conditions on e.g. the <PostbuildEvent> item or surrounding <ItemDefinitionGroup>

Comment: @Florian, yes, it works. Thank you!

Comment: @stijn, `MSBuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release` works well! With post-build event. Thank you!
Now I have two possible options, using `cmake` or using `msbuild`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

You can use CMake's `--build` [command line option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) (which does abstract the `make`/`msbuild`/`ninja`... calls) with something like:

```
cmake --build . --target INSTALL --config Release
```